# AVPlayer's addPeriodicTimeObserver function is not being executed properly

Tags: swift, macos, notifications, avfoundation, appkit

#### Background

I am trying to get a very basic audio player set up in a macOS application. I am using **Xcode 9.3** on **macOS 10.13.4**.

---

#### Setup

I have a `MediaManager` class to control the `AVPlayer` object:

```
let EPISODE_SELECTED_KEY = "EPISODE_SELECTED"

class MediaManager {
    
    static var shared: MediaManager = MediaManager()
    
    var player: AVPlayer?
    
    var currentFile: URL? {
        didSet {
            if (currentFile != nil) {
                play(URL: currentFile!)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(EPISODE_SELECTED_KEY), object: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    
    func play(URL: URL) {
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: URL)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        player?.play()
    }

}
```

To visually track the progress of the audio item being played, I am subclassing `NSSlider` as so:

```
class PlayerSlider: NSSlider {
    
    var observerToken: Any?
    var mediaManager = MediaManager.shared
    
    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            // Register for PlayerManager notification.
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setupPlayerObserver), name: Notification.Name(EPISODE_SELECTED_KEY), object: nil)
        }
    }
    
    override var doubleValue: Double {
        didSet {
            // Make sure the player has an active item.
            guard mediaManager.currentEpisode != nil || mediaManager.currentFile != nil else {
                return
            }
            // Update player with slider's position.
            let seekTime = CMTime(seconds: (mediaManager.player?.currentTime().seconds)! * (doubleValue / 100), preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            mediaManager.player?.seek(to: seekTime)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func setupPlayerObserver() {
        // Setup observer to update UI every 0.5 seconds.
        let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.5, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        self.observerToken = mediaManager.player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: .main, using: { (time) in
            // Update slider value to audio item progress.
            let duration = self.mediaManager.player!.currentItem!.duration.seconds
            let seekTime = self.mediaManager.player!.currentTime().seconds
            self.doubleValue = seekTime / duration * 100
        })
        
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I'm just set the `currentFile` property of the `MediaManager` singleton to a local file.

---

#### Problem

In the block that I pass to the `addPeriodicTimeObserver` function, if I comment out everything the file plays fine. However, if there's even a print statement in there, nothing happens. The file never plays and the app just hangs.

---

#### Questions

1. What is going on inside that block? Even a single statement stops the `AVPlayer` from playing.
2. Is this a good design for an audio file player? To have the `MediaManager` singleton and the listener inside the `PlayerSlider`.

Answer (score 3):

What you've written is asking the periodic observer to to call you back every 0.5*10<sup>9</sup>seconds, but that 0.5 is rounded down to 0, so it's every 0 seconds. Neither are possible (why doesn't `addPeriodicTimeObserver` mention that?), so try

```
let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 10)  // every tenth of a second, say
```

Comment: You're right, I meant to write `CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 10)`. I guess I was a victim of autocompletion. That must have been a very slow periodic observer. Updating. Thanks!